# du wrongly reports empty directory

Tags: disk-usage

I'm using these commands:

```
du -sh --apparent-size ./*
du -sh ./*
```

both reporting:

```
4.0K    ./Lightroom_catalog_from_win_backup
432M    ./Lightroom catalog - wine_backup
```

while those directories contain:

```
$ll ./"Lightroom catalog - wine_backup"
total 432M
-rwxrwx--- 1 gigi gigi 432M Mar 18  2018 Lightroom 5 Catalog Linux.lrcat
-rwxrwx--- 1 gigi gigi  227 Nov 21  2015 zbackup.bat
$ll ./Lightroom_catalog_from_win_backup
total 396M
-rwxrwx--- 3 gigi gigi 396M Dec 17 09:35 Lightroom 5 Catalog Linux.lrcat
-rwxrwx--- 3 gigi gigi  227 Dec 17 09:35 zbackup.bat
```

Why `du` is reporting `4.0K` for ./Lightroom_catalog_from_win_backup and how could I make it to report correctly?

PS: other system information:

```
$stat --file-system $HOME
  File: "/home/gigi"
    ID: 5b052c62a5a527bb Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 720651086  Free: 155672577  Available: 119098665
Inodes: Total: 183050240  Free: 178896289

$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: To build on the answers already given so far, what does `/bin/ls -li './*/Lightroom 5 Catalog Linux.lrcat'` return?

Comment: `ls -li ./*/"Lightroom 5 Catalog Linux.lrcat"
36831321 -rwxrwx--- 1 gigi gigi 432M Mar 18  2018 ./Lightroom catalog - wine_backup/Lightroom 5 Catalog Linux.lrcat
36833201 -rwxrwx--- 3 gigi gigi 396M Dec 17 09:35 ./Lightroom_catalog_from_win_backup/Lightroom 5 Catalog Linux.lrcat`

Comment: This presents a problem with the answers since the file with the link count of three is not being counted elsewhere in the `du` command. So you have only two subdirectories in your working directory?

Comment: no, I have approximately 15 others

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can reproduce if the files are hard links:

```
~ mkdir foo bar
~ dd if=/dev/urandom of=bar/file1 count=1k bs=1k
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.00985276 s, 106 MB/s
~ ln bar/file1 foo/file1
~ du -sh --apparent-size foo bar
1.1M    foo
4.0K    bar
```

This is expected behaviour. From [the GNU `du` docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html):

> If two or more hard links point to the same file, only one of the hard
>   links is counted. The file argument order affects which links are
>   counted, and changing the argument order may change the numbers and
>   entries that du outputs.

If you really need repeated sizes of hard links, try the `-l` option:

> ‘`-l`’
>   ‘`--count-links`’
>   Count the size of all files, even if they have appeared already (as a
>   hard link).

```
~ du -sh --apparent-size foo bar -l
1.1M    foo
1.1M    bar
```

Answer (score 15):

Notice how the link count is `3` for the two files `Lightroom 5 Catalog Linux.lrcat` and `zbackup.bat` in `Lightroom_catalog_from_win_backup`.

This means that these two files are hard linked to (additional names for) other files somewhere.  When you run `du` on a directory or a set of files, each hard link is only counted once.

Example:

```
$ ls -l
total 41024
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  10485760 Dec 17 09:07 file1
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  10485760 Dec 17 09:07 file2

$ du -h file1
10.0M   file1

$ du -h file2
10.0M   file2

$ du -h .
10.0M   .
```

This behaviour is explicitly mandated by [the POSIX standard for the `du` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html):

> A file that occurs multiple times under one file operand and that has a link count greater than 1 shall be counted and written for only one entry.

Some `du` implementations have non-standard options to disable this behaviour.  For GNU `du`, this is done with the `-l` option.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly working correctly. `du` counts each file only once regardless of how many times it's referenced. It's probable that your two directories contain the same set of hard-linked files.

The man page for GNU `du` offers `-l`, `--count-links` to switch off this standard optimisation (see `man du` to check if your implementation includes this). Or you run `du` twice, once for each directory.